# AttachConsole() does not take user-input as expected

Tags: c++, windows, desktop-application

We have an app which can run in both GUI and Console mode – so we make it as SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.  Now, when it is invoked from Console, we want it to ‘run in console mode’ by ‘attaching to the parent console’. For this, we are using AttachConsole() and stdin/stdout is streamed to this console. as shown in the below code :

```
if(AttachConsole (ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) == 0){

    // Not launched from a console

}else{

    // launched via a console

        FILE *  fpstdin = stdin, *fpstdout = stdout, *fpstderr = stderr;

    freopen_s (&fpstdin,  "CONIN$",  "r", stdin);
    freopen_s (&fpstdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen_s (&fpstderr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

}
```

The built application (exe) is run from cmd. When we do this, we observe few issues :

1. When the exe is launched from cmd, the expectation is that the exe specific user interaction (i.e. input / output) should continue in the same cmd terminal without the cmd prompt re-appearing in-between. However the observation is the cmd prompt reappears in-between the exe specific user interaction. Image provided below for reference:
   [stdin issue with AttachConsole()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuqVP.png)
2. Running the exe shows the cmd prompt again and then the output of the application comes i.e.

   C:\Test>MySampleApp.exe

   C:\Test>This is the output from MySampleApp.exe... etc etc..

Can you tell us what we are doing wrong ?

Comment: cmd.exe does not know that it has to wait with displaying its prompt, and read input, until the launched program terminates.  Especially reading input is troublesome, good odds that whatever the user types is interpreted by cmd.exe instead of your program.  The user has to start your program with `start /wait yourapp.exe` to avoid this problem.  Of course they won't, so you should not do this.  Create another console mode app that doesn't do anything but launch your original app.  You can rename it to yourapp.com and it will be launched when the user types "yourapp".

Answer (score 0):

To me this works (?) (I don’t know much about what I wrote in the code, I’m beginner using the Windows API, C and C++).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(
    const HINSTANCE _In_     CurrInst,
    const HINSTANCE _In_opt_ PrevInst,
    const PTSTR     _In_     CmdLine ,
    const int       _In_     CmdShow ) {;


    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) == 0) {

        // Not launched from a console

        AllocConsole();

        FILE * fpstdin  = stdin,
             * fpstdout = stdout,
             * fpstderr = stderr;

        _tfreopen_s(&fpstdin, _T("CONIN$"), _T("r"), stdin);
        _tfreopen_s(&fpstdout, _T("CONOUT$"), _T("w"), stdout);
        _tfreopen_s(&fpstderr, _T("CONOUT$"), _T("w"), stderr);

        std::cout << "Attached!\n";
        std::cin.get();

    } else {

        // Launched from a console

        AllocConsole();

        FILE * fpstdin  = stdin , 
             * fpstdout = stdout,
             * fpstderr = stderr;

        _tfreopen_s(&fpstdin , _T("CONIN$" ), _T("r"), stdin );
        _tfreopen_s(&fpstdout, _T("CONOUT$"), _T("w"), stdout);
        _tfreopen_s(&fpstderr, _T("CONOUT$"), _T("w"), stderr);


        std::cout << "Not Attached!\n";
        std::cin.get();

    }

    FreeConsole();

}
```

I think it might be useful to encapsulate some of these instructions and you could use RAII on Alloc/Free Console?

Edit : And yes, i see the "duplicated code".